# HTML onsubmit event not returning elements

Tags: javascript, onsubmit

I cannot get input text by using onsubmit event on form what to do? Kindly guide me. This is the code. In this code I've added an input element and a submit element. I want to obtain input element's value after submitting the form but I can't.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<body>

    <form onsubmit="myfunction()">
        Text Input: <input type="text" id="tableInput">
        <input type="submit" value="get text input">
    </form>

</body>
<script>


function myfunction() {
      var num = document.getElementById("tableInput").value;
      alert(num);

    }
</script>

</html>
```

Comment: You don't call your function at any point, so of course it isn't working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to fix your selector. id of `input` is `"tableInput"`, so you need to pass in `"tableInput"` to `getElementById`:

```
function myfunction() {
      var num = document.getElementById("tableInput").value;
      alert(num);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<body>

    <form onsubmit="myfunction()">
        Text Input: <input type="text" id="tableInput">
        <input type="submit" value="get text input">
    </form>

</body>
<script>


function myfunction() {
      var num = document.getElementById("tableInput").value;
      alert(num);
}
</script>

</html>
```

Comment: If you run the code snippet, you will see the alert

Comment: Thank you so much @jh314. This works for me my problem solved.. :)

Answer (score 1):

```js
    function myfunction() {
          var id = document.getElementById("idOfTheField").value;
          var name = document.getElementById("cars").value;
          var t = document.getElementById("cars");
var selectedText = t.options[t.selectedIndex].text;
          alert('id is : ' + id + ' name is : ' + name + 'car : ' + selectedText);

     }
```

```html
    <form onsubmit='myfunction()'>
    <label>id: </label><br>

    <input type='text' value='' id='idOfTheField' name='idField' /><br>

    <label>name: </label><br>

    <input type='text' value='' id='idOfTheNameField' name='nameField'/><br>
    <label>select a car : </label><br>
   <select name="cars" id='cars'>
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
    <option value="fiat">Fiat</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
  </select>

    <input type='submit' value='submit' />
    </form>
```

Problem is `document.getElementById` javascript methods yields the id of the field. so you need to provide the id only. `id='thisIsID'` then the id is `thisIsID` ..

in my answer shows how you should do this with jquery as well
Hope this helps

```js
function myfunction() {
      let num = $('#tableInput').val();
      alert(num);

    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<body>

    <form onsubmit="myfunction()">
        Text Input: <input type="text" id="tableInput">
        <input type="submit" value="get text input">
    </form>

</body>


</html>
```

Comment: Sir is there any method yo get values after submitting form without using jQuery?

Comment: Im nuwan not sir. anyway after submitting means ? do you want to get submitted values to server side or client side?

Comment: I just want to obtain values from input boxes to javascript variables.. after clicking submit button.

Comment: added a pure javascript implementation as well .. hope this helps